# When and why can you omit “when” (or other conjunctions or prepositions) before a gerund clause that’s used adverbially?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbials, when, gerund-phrases

> 1. I had a bad experience working there.

Is that sentence correct, or must I write:

> 2. I had a bad experience **when** working there.
> 3. I had a bad experience **while** working there.

or even:

> 4. I had a bad experience **while I was** working there.
> 5. I had a bad experience **when I worked** there.

It seems like sometimes gerund–participle clauses (meaning *-ing* clauses) can be directly used in an adverbial way, without any sort of conjunction or preposition joining them to the rest of the sentence.

> 6. Working there, I developed a real sweet tooth.
> 7. **While** working there, I developed a real sweet tooth.
> 8. **By** working there, I developed a real sweet tooth.
> 9. I developed a real sweet tooth working there.
> 10. I developed a real sweet tooth **while** working there.
> 11. I developed a real sweet tooth **by** working there.

Are there rules governing when you can use a gerund clause on its own like this without a connecting word?

Comment: All of these gerund clauses refer to time periods, so the _when_ or _while_  can be deleted without changing anything. However, not all gerund clauses refer to time periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional words you are using all add meaning to the sentence.

'**When**' indicates a there was a specific time in the past (although it is not specified).

'**While**' indicates it occurred during the course of a broader time in the past.

'**By**' indicates it was the cause of the experience.

The rule would be that you use a connecting word that adds the correct additional meaning, or don't if the meaning is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering as one who cares about effective communication, not as a grammarian.

It hits my ear as ambiguous.  Possible meanings:

- "There is a bad experience in play here (working here)."
- Or, "As a result of my on-going status of being employed where (working here), I have this history, this bad experience."

I suspect you intended the second meaning.  I might have said instead:

- "I had a bad experience working here."
- Or, "I had a bad experience while working here."

Either avoids the ambiguity, and keeps the reader moving along without having to work to resolve your intended meaning.

Comment: It would appear my focus on eliminating ambiguity in language was not appreciated by one drive-by voter.  I would have appreciated them posting a comment as to why they were not compelled the same argument as I was.  A shame.